# Problems when deploying a django application using nginx and uwsgi?

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, django-wsgi

I'm having problems when I'm trying to deploy my **Django** application using **nginx** and **uwsgi** . I will start by putting here the config files:

**tutorial_nginx.conf**

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/mrgrj/site/blog/tutorial.sock;
}
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name xx.xx.xxx.xx;

    location /media  {
        alias /home/mrgrj/site/blog/polls/templates;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/mrgrj/site/blog/polls/templates/polls;
    }
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass django;
        include /home/mrgrj/site/blog/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

**tutorial_uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]

chdir           = /home/mrgrj/site/blog
module          = wusgi.py
home            = /home/mrgrj/site

master          = true
processes       = 10
socket          = /home/mrgrj/site/blog/tutorial.sock
vacuum          = true
```

I followed this tutorial from [Official Django Documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) and unfortunately I didn't succeed to finish it as I encountered some issues.

The nginx server is set up correctly as it displays me the right page when I access the ip from the web browser. The django application is working when I am running `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. The issues that I have, regarding that tutorial:

- `uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite.wsgi` . I don't have such a file, but I have something simillar which is called **wsgy.py**:

  ```
  import os
  from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "blog.settings")
  application = get_wsgi_application()
  ```

When I am trying tu run that command using `wsgi.py` it says `Internal server error` on my browser ( I am accessing it via `ip:8000` ). Traceback:

> *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.10 (64bit) on [Sun Apr 12 16:42:15 2015]**  compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 10 April 2015 08:25:41 os:
>   Linux-3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014
>   nodename: alex-test machine: x86_64 clock source: unix detected number
>   of CPU cores: 1 current working directory: /home/mrgrj/site/blog/blog
>   detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi !!! no internal routing
>   support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
>    **WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager**  your processes number limit is 3750 your memory page size is 4096 bytes detected max file descriptor number: 1024 lock engine: pthread
>   robust mutexes thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with
>   --thunder-lock) uWSGI http bound on :8000 fd 4 spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 2169) uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:41225 (port
>   auto-assigned) fd 3 Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014,
>   23:03:41)  [GCC 4.8.2]
>    **Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads**  Python main interpreter initialized at 0x122d0c0 your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections your
>   mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds mapped 72760
>   bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
>    **Operational MODE: single process**  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./wsgi.py", line 16, in 
>       application = get_wsgi_application()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14,
>   in get_wsgi_application
>       django.setup()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/**init**.py", line 17,
>   in setup
>       configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/**init**.py",
>   line 48, in **getattr**
>       self._setup(name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line
>   44, in _setup
>       self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line
>   92, in **init**
>       mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name) ImportError: No module named blog.settings unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
>    **no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode** 
>    **uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode *** spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 2168, cores: 1)

Another problem that I have is when I am trying to run `uwsgi --socket :8001 --wsgi-file test.py`. It gives me a `**no data received message**` `(Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.)'

Can anybody help me out, please ?

Comment: Do you have any traceback in your terminal when you get the 500 while trying torun it on :8000?

Comment: I added it to the main thread @Hevlastka . Take a look.

Comment: `ImportError: No module named blog.settings` This is the actual error you'll need to fix. Seems like the path to your settings file specified in your wsgi.py isn't correct.

Comment: Look at `tutorial_uwsgi.ini`:

`[uwsgi]
chdir           = /home/mrgrj/site/blog` --> you go into blog subdir  and then try to open settings file blog.settings. So python is looking to import blog.blog.settings. Change either the uWSGI config file (chdir to _site_ rather than _site/blog_) or the wsgi.py file (DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE).